# Appending value to keys in set

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a set

```
codes = {'Code1', 'Code2', 'Code3'}
```

And I'd like to ultimately get a dictionary with the following output

```
code_dict = {'Code1': 'Input_Code1', 'Code2': 'Input_Code2', 'Code3': 'Input_Code3'}
```

I've tried using `dict.fromkeys()` but my output was entirely messed up

```
for code in codes:
    code_dict = dict.fromkeys(codes, "Input_" + code)
```

I also tried assigning the value in `codes` to istelf using

```
codes = codes | {c for c in codes}
```

But that didn't work either. I'm relatively new to dictionaries so please excuse me if the answer is right in front of my nose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dict.fromkeys()` does not take an expression for the values; you get a dictionary with *all the same values* (technically, all the values are references to one object, shared between keys).

Your loop just created an entirely new dictionary for every `code` in the `codes` set, each replacing the previous object `code_dict` was bound to. In the end you'd have a dictionary with all keys set to the same value, where the value is based on whatever element in the unordered set was produced last when iterating.

Use a dict comprehension if you need to produce different values:

```
code_dict = {code: "Input_" + code for code in codes}
```

A dictionary comprehension executes two expressions on the left-hand side for each iteration of the loop, one producing the key (`code` for the above example), and one for the value (here the concatenation of a string literal and `code`).

A demo of correct use of `dict.fromkeys()` and the dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> codes = {'Code1', 'Code2', 'Code3'}
>>> dict.fromkeys(codes, 'The same value for all keys')
{'Code3': 'The same value for all keys', 'Code1': 'The same value for all keys', 'Code2': 'The same value for all keys'}
>>> {code: "Input_" + code for code in codes}
{'Code3': 'Input_Code3', 'Code1': 'Input_Code1', 'Code2': 'Input_Code2'}
```

Comment: Awesome! What would be a way to get around the `"unhashable type: 'set'"` error? My set is coming directly from `codes = set(codedvalues)`.

Comment: @ATCH_torn: are you trying to use the *whole set* as a key somethere? Check you don't have `code` and `codes` mixed up in your implementation.

Comment: I did have it mixed up. Thanks so much for the help!